# unicorn error with rails root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I'm creating a rails app with Rails 3.2.6.
I would like to connect unicorn and nginx, however, but I'm having the following error:

```
/path/to/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/unicorn-4.3.1/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:492:in `working_directory': config_file=unicorn.conf.minimal.rb would not be accessible in working_directory=/path/to/rails/app (ArgumentError)
```

I think my config files are wrong, but how to work them?

I use this `unicorn.conf.minimal.rb`

```
working_directory "/path/to/rails/app"
listen "/path/to/app/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock", :backlog => 64
listen 8080 # by default Unicorn listens on port 8080
worker_processes 2 # this should be >= nr_cpus
pid "/home/paisen/shour_teaser/config/unicorn/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "/path/to/rails/app/config/unicorn/log/stderr.log"
stdout_path "/path/to/rails/app/config/unicorn/log/stdout.log"
```

Answer (score 2):

See the words `would not be accessible`,it maybe a permission issues,check out your login user.

But likely is configured result.

so you think `my config files are wrong`,[here](https://gist.github.com/3052776) is a Nginx+Unicorn best-practices congifuration guide.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a little stale, but i ran into this and the problem was that my unicorn.rb working_directory was pointed to the wrong location.  After fixing that it started right up with.  This was on ubuntu 12.04 server

```
bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -D
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the error for me. I forgot that I had previously modified the path in my Capistrano recipe.